# Why do I have to explicitly implement an interface member of type object when the member has already been implemented with another type?

Tags: c#, generics, object, interface

Consider the following example:

```
namespace Test
{
    interface IContract : IContract<object> { }

    interface IContract<T>
    {
        void Definition(T data);
    }

    public class SomeClass : IContract, IContract<SomeContractClass>
    {
        public void Definition(SomeContractClass data)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public class SomeContractClass { }
}
```

I thought I would have satisfied the interface by supplying `Definition(SomeContractClass data)` since as stated in [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/9kkx3h3c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> In the unified type system of C#, all types, predefined and
>   user-defined, reference types and value types, inherit directly or
>   indirectly from Object.

But instead the compiler asks me to define it explicitly:

> Error 1   'Test.SomeClass' does not implement interface member
>   'Test.IContract.Definition(object)'

Comment: Apologies in advance if it's a stupid question, it took me a while to come up with the title and this probably prevented me from finding the solution outside of posting a question.

Comment: You aren't implementing anything for IContract<object> ? It looks like there is a public void Definition(object data) or something in that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are implementing the interface `IContract`.

If we flatten the inheritance heirarchy, we can see that `IContract` essentially looks like this:

```
interface IContract
{
    void Definition(object data);
}
```

You do not supply a method matching the signature `void Definition (object data)` - the method you supply takes a `SomeContractClass` instead. Therefore, you get the stated error message.

However, I think the underlying issue is that your class implements both `IContract` and `IContract<T>` (which is the same as saying `IContract<object>` and `IContract<T>`). I think your design needs some work...

Comment: You're right about the 'design', it needs ctrl+a then del.  I was playing around and ended up with the situation and had a burning question about it.  The term 'signature' has given me the bulb I needed - the interface wants me to satisfy the 'signature', regardless of the usage. I clearly haven't done that.

Answer (score 3):

I will make a litle analogy of your situation.

You have a small company that repairs small cars.

You sign a contract with the government who needs a repair service for any type of vehicle in their diplomatic fleet (airplanes, boats, big trucks, and small cars).

You lied / made a small error the moment you made the generalization that

1) since you successfully implement

```
void Repair(SmallCar vehicle)
```

2) and because

```
class SmallCar : Vehicle { }
class Airplane : Vehicle { }
class Boat : Vehicle { }
class BigTruck : Vehicle { }
```

somehow, the combining of points (1 + 2) => point 3 which states:

3) The government can safely refer to your small company as "The guys who repair anything" and
someday consider it a good idea to ask your company to help them like so:

```
Airplane protocolPlane = new Airplane();
yourCompany.Repair(protocolPlane);
```

which is of course not true: **(1 + 2) do not imply (3)**

It's a good thing that this ended up as a compiler error and not runtime exception. This way you learn sooner about a small problem in the architecture.

**EDIT**

In your code, if you decide you really need to implement both interfaces in the **SomeClass** class and you don't know how to do that, you could use explicit interface implementation like so:

```
public class SomeClass : IContract, IContract<SomeContractClass>
{
    // Method of IContract<SomeContractClass>
    public void Definition(SomeContractClass data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing a SomeContractClass instance");            
        // ...etc
    }
    // Method of IContract hence of IContract<object>
    void IContract<object>.Definition(object data)
    {
        if (data is SomeContractClass)
          this.Definition(data as SomeContractClass);
        else
        {
          string descriptor = (null == data) 
            ? "A null reference" 
            : "An instance of " + data.GetType().Name";
          Console.WriteLine("Processing something other than a SomeContractClass instance: " + descriptor);
          // ...etc
        }
    }

}
```

This way, you will successfully get the following results:

```
class Program {
     public static void Main(string[] args) {
         SomeClass someInstance = new SomeClass();
         IContract<SomeContractClass> first= someInstance;
         IContract second = someInstance;

         someInstance.Definition(new SomeContractClass()); 
         // prints out "Processing a SomeContractClass instance"

         first.Definition(new SomeContractClass());
         // prints out "Processing a SomeContractClass instance"

         second.Definition(new SomeContractClass());
         // prints out "Processing a SomeContractClass instance"

         second.Definition( "something else" );
         // prints "Processing something other 
         // than a SomeContractClass instance: An instance of String"

         second.Definition( 123 );
         // prints "Processing something other
         // than a SomeContractClass instance: An instance of Int32"

         first.Definition( true );
         // doesn't compile saying that bool can't be converted to SomeContractClass

     }
}
```

**END OF EDIT**

Comment: Good analogy, but I think you meant `void Repair(Vehicle vehicle)`, not `SmallCar`.

Comment: Thanks, and maybe I didn't express myself clear enough. What I wanted to say is that: although in reality, "the company" only implements the repair service for small cars (not anything) it is trying to sign a contract that states they can handle anything... So the place where I wrote "SmallCar" and **not** "Vehicle" is not the contract but the actual truth (which is in contradiction with the contract)

Comment: @RB: btw, sorry for not stopping writing my little analogy although I noticed "someone" had answered already (I had so much momentum when that ajax notification appeared I just couldn't stop :)) You have my upvote :)

Comment: @RB: I made an edit to the answer. Hope it's clearer now... :)

Comment: Thanks for your time answering, it's clearer now.  I was focusing on the usage, where the interface is a real hard (!) contract - I needed to satisfy the signature.

Comment: Please also check the latest edit which shows how you could implement both interfaces kinda safely. Please also make sure you check out @Eric Lippert's awesome series entitled "Covariance and Contravariance in C#" (parts One through Eleven) whenever you have the time and you're in the mood for fabulousness :). The first post and eleventh posts are: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/07/covariance-and-contravariance-part-twelve-to-infinity-but-not-beyond.aspx